# How to remove carriage returns and new lines in Postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am stuck again trying to get my data in a format that I need it in. I have a text field that looks like this.

> "deangelo 001 deangelo
>
> local origin of name: italain
>
> from the american name deangelo
>
> meaning: of the angels
>
> emotional spectrum • he is a fountain of joy for all.
>
> personal integrity • his good name is his most precious asset.
> personality • it’s hard to soar with eagles when you’re surrounded by
> turkeys! relationships • starts slowly, but a relationship with
> deangelo builds over time. travel & leisure • a trip of a lifetime
> is in his future.
>
> career & money • a gifted child, deangelo will need to be
> challenged constantly.
>
> life’s opportunities • joy and happiness await this blessed person.
>
> deangelo’s lucky numbers: 12 • 38 • 18 • 34 • 29 • 16
>
> "

What would the best way be in Postgresql to remove the carriage returns and new lines? I've tried several things and none of them want to behave.

```
select regexp_replace(field, E'\r\c', '  ', 'g') from mytable
    WHERE id = 5520805582

SELECT regexp_replace(field, E'[^\(\)\&\/,;\*\:.\>\<[:space:]a-zA-Z0-9-]', ' ')
    FROM mytable
    WHERE field~ E'[^\(\)\&\/,;\*\:.\<\>[:space:]a-zA-Z0-9-]'
    AND id = 5520805582;
```

Answer (score 228, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace(field, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' )
```

read the manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: You can get rid of the double slashes if you dropped the `E` prefix: `'[\n\r]+'`. Much cleaner looking, imo.

Comment: The linked documentation contains the following text:


```
The flags parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag i specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag g specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one. Supported flags (though not g) are described in Table 9-20.
```

Comment: @Jens as with other regex-engines, `'g'` here allows total replacement. Without it, replacements will only occur once per "line," which in this case pretty much just means "only once," given that Postgres doesn't count `\n`s as linebreaks.

Comment: UPDATE MYTABLENAME AS u SET name = regexp_replace(u.name, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g') ;  This will change the name field for the entire table.

Answer (score 47):

```
select regexp_replace(field, E'[\\n\\r\\u2028]+', ' ', 'g' )
```

I had the same problem in my postgres d/b, but the newline in question wasn't the traditional ascii CRLF, it was a unicode line separator, character U2028. The above code snippet will capture that unicode variation as well.

*Update... although I've only ever encountered the aforementioned characters "in the wild", to follow lmichelbacher's advice to translate even more [unicode newline-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) characters, use this:*

```
select regexp_replace(field, E'[\\n\\r\\f\\u000B\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]+', ' ', 'g' )
```

Comment: You might want to add other "newline-y" Unicode characters to that regular expression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode

Answer (score 44):

OP asked specifically about regexes since it would appear there's concern for a number of other characters as well as newlines, but for those *just* wanting strip out newlines, you don't even need to go to a regex. You can simply do:

```
select replace(field,E'\n','');
```

I think this is an SQL-standard behavior, so it should extend back to all but perhaps the very earliest versions of Postgres. The above tested fine for me in 9.4 and 9.2

Comment: I want to remind everyone that `replace` replaces exact match of second parameter, not every character of it.

Comment: Bonus points for avoiding regex!

Answer (score 17):

In the case you need to remove line breaks from the begin or end of the string, you may use this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = regexp_replace(field, E'(^[\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)', '', 'g' );
```

Have in mind that the hat **`^`** means the begin of the string and the dollar sign **`$`** means the end of the string.

Hope it help someone.

Comment: Thank you very much for the $ Hint at the end of the string, that was what I was searching for