# How to export postgres data containing newlines to CSV without breaking records on several lines

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to export data from postgresq to CSV files but when I do have newlines in text in the database, the exported data will be broken on several lines, which makes much harder to read the CSV file, not to say that most applications will fail to load it properly.

Here is how I export the data now:

```
 PRESQL="\pset format unaligned
 \pset fieldsep \",\"
 \pset footer off
 \o 'out.csv'
 "
 cat <(echo $PRESQL) $QUERYFILE | psql …
```

Sa far, so good, unless you have newlines in the text fields. Any hack that would allow me to generate a very simple to parse CSV file (with one record per line)?

Answer (score 2):

It was a mistake to consider that a CSV can be forced to have one line per row. The RFC states clear that newlines are to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replace() or regexp_replace() function.

The answer to the followinig SO question should give you an idea: [How to remove carriage returns and new lines in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836906/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-and-new-lines-in-postgresql)