# What chars represents new line in postgresql?

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, newline

I exported data from mySQL and imported them to 
PostgreSQL. 
Everything went fine except one thing.

Lots of text fields in mySQL had newline in it and now they are imported in PostgreSQL as \r\n. What char represents new line in PostgreSQL?

I was using data from mySQL db in my C# program. It was displaying new lines correctly. Now it shows \r\n in text.

I tried to replace all \r\n with \n, or \n. Nothing works.

Comment: How are you inserting your data, and how are you fetching it? Are you displaying it in .NET in both cases, or are you saying it "shows" `\r\n` in some PostgreSQL tool? How did you perform the export/import? There's a lot of information missing in this question.

Comment: In pgAdmin (tool added with postgresql) it shows \r\n. I inserted the data using insert commands, that were exported in mysql

Comment: Well that may just be how it's displayed in pgAdmin. Have you tried fetching it in C# and displaying it? You may well find it's fine there. (Just like the way that in the debugger, the string would be displayed with the escape sequences.)

Comment: my question is what chars represents new line in postgresql ;) so I can simply replace \r\n chars with it

Comment: it shows \r\n in c#. I'm using NpgSQL dll

Comment: You've missed my point - the database is just storing data. I suspect it's storing the exact data that was in mySQL, it's just that pgAdmin isn't *displaying* it using line breaks, but showing you an escaped format. What's really important to you: what's stored in the database, or what gets shown in pgAdmin?

Comment: Okay, if it's showing `\r\n` when you display it in a WinForms app (*not* the debugger!), that's a different matter. I suspect you basically need to find the escaping rules of PostgreSQL, and escape the carriage return and line feed differently in the script exported from MySQL. This isn't really about line breaks - it's about escaping.

Comment: Hmm... the Postgres documentation suggests that it should be fine if your insert script just uses `\r\n`. Could you include a sample insert in your question?

Comment: `insert into color (r, g, b, name) values (1, 2, 3, 'abc \r\n cde');`

Comment: if I read it in c# and display in for example DataGridView it displays string `"abc \r\n cde"`. I also tried to insert new lines in strings directly from pgAdmin and it saves new lines but after I display it in c# it shows abc##cde. ## - are weird [][] double small boxes chars. It seems maybe its a problem with c# characters coding

Comment: It sounds like you really need better diagnostics of what you're getting in C#. Ideally write a small console app to fetch a single value, and then display each UTF-16 code unit within it: `foreach (char c in text) Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", (int) c);`

Comment: those chars [][] are char(13) and char(10), \ is char(92), \n he sees as 2 chars char(92) and char(110)

Comment: Then that sounds like it's a matter of `DataGridView` not handling multiple lines. Try putting it in a TextBox. It's not clear to me how you're getting 13 and 10 (which are \r and \n) *and* the backslashes. Again, it would help if we could see some code.

Comment: my mysql version of that app shows newlines in datagridview. Will code simple app and paste code here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already imported it wrong, and assuming all the data is escaped, you can update the values as this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = 
    replace(replace(replace(replace(your_column,
        '\r', E'\r'),
        '\n', E'\n'),
        '\t', E'\t'),
        '\\', '\');
```

Notice this can lead to some errors, e.g., if it really should be `\r` (not escaped) here.

PostgreSQL follows the SQL ANSI, which means that the only escape of a string is two single-quotes, for instance `'I''m a rock star'` will generate `I'm a rock star`, but `'I\'m a rock star'` will lead to an error, because backslash is not an escape char and so you closed the string after the `m`. This rule can be broken if (1) you use the letter `E` (as in sample) before the string, this cause a backslash escape (as usual); or (2) if you set the GUC parameter `standard_conforming_strings` to `off` (it is not recommended, but you can do that during your import, depending on how this process has been made, it would work).

Comment: you're genius ! I don't really understand how this E works but it is working. It fixed everything

Comment: @gemGreg, simple, regular SQL strings does not escape at all (except two single-quotes), to make them escape, you have to use `E`...

Answer (score 0):

New line character would change according to where it is coming from or being displayed on(Windows/Web).

As far as removing new line characters is concerned have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837322/87956)

Comment: Removing \r\n from text fields is not a problem. problem is that I WANT to have newline chars in that place where was \r\n. I'm displaying it in c# using Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand and Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader reading base and then dr.getString(...)