# Removing line feed from a postgres table

Tags: postgresql

Can any one help me to remove the line feeds in a postgres table which is created as

```
CREATE TABLE details
(
  doc_id serial NOT NULL,
  doc_name character varying(255),
  doc_description character varying(255),
  doc_location oid
)
```

Line feed has to be removed from the doc_location column.

Thanks,
Karthi

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the manual, and the description of the string functions in there? What's your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836906/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-and-new-lines-in-postgresql) help? Please do search before asking. Correct answer is the first link when googling title of your question.