# Identical strings difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm collecting procedures definitions from multiple databases using pg_get_functiondef(oid).

By comparing them in various difference tools it shows they are identical, but simple = in SQL shows FALSE.
I casted these strings into bytea and it revealed that in some of them, newlines are saved differently.

For example:

```
\015\012
```

vs

```
\012
```

How to get rid of these differences on bytea level and receive true when comparing such strings?

Comment: the first comes from windows the last from linux, you can replace \n with \r}n with regreplace

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836906/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-and-new-lines-in-postgresql so you can compare them if all new line characters are the same